# The html component not overflowing

Tags: jasper-reports

The *JasperReports*'s html component overflows by width and prints in *iReport*. But in application the overflowing part is sliced out and is not showing up.

Please find the following image for understanding my problem[image: In iReport the content prints]

[image: In Application when exported as pdf, the content is missing]

First image is from *iReport* and second one is when printed through my application.

Comment: also what ever the width i give to the html component in report, It's content always overflows

Comment: Hello. Im facing same problem, any solution ? Thanks

Comment: Hi jNivk.... I am really sorry I couldnt help you with it... I feel it would be better if you can ask the same in ireports discussion board....

Comment: I know it has been about a year ago, but did you find any issue ? I'm facing the exact same problem, by doing a cover page and the HTML component appearing only in the area defined (and so, ridiculously small)

Comment: I am sorry Jacks.. I have not found any solutions. In my case the shrinking contents were comments and hence I just showed first 2 comments and then just  shown the count like +3 comments. IF you feel the question is useful, please upvote it so that others will view this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm wondering if it is related to the PDF printer  you're using .. In fact, now that I look at your post, I had the same problem but when printing on a paper, and I saw that the printer preferences were not adjusted. Maybe this could be a hint of your problem ?

Comment: Thanks Jacks.. Will think in that way..

Comment: Maybe post some code or write a snippet to represent your problem, I'm curious about that issue. I've read that the HTML component for Jasper Reports is buggy and not recommended. Try using a simple Text component and set the "Markup" parameter as "HTML", maybe this could solve your problem in any way ..